# How get control from non-window class in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Application.Current.MainWindow. ?

Comment: This is a poorly worded question, but it was clearly enough for someone to give an answer. I'm adding +1 votes to take it out of the negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your control is in the main window of your application, you most likely need to cast it to the appropriate type.  For example, if your "main window" is named `Window1` (default naming), you could do:

```
Window1 myWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as Window1;
if (myWindow != null)
{
     Button myButton = myWindow.button1; // Use your control here...
     myButton.IsEnabled = true; // Do something with the control here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another example that's very similar to Reed's reply above, here's an event handler (app.xaml.cs) that updates text displayed in a status bar (MainWindow.xaml):

```cs
private void Control_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not select text for read-only text boxes.
    if ((sender is TextBox) && (!(sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly))
    {
        (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
    }

    // Update status bar text to display control tag value.
    (Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("statusBarTextBlock")
        as TextBlock).Text = (sender as Control).Tag.ToString();
}
```